# how to override QSqlRelationalTableModel?

Tags: c++, database, qt

I want to add a column in the last.
I want to put QPushButtons to that column.
However,I don't know how to do that.
Concerns are below.

1. when I override data(const QModelIndex &index, int role), I have to rewrite all the data, is that avoidable?`
2. when I return new QPushButton as QVariant, it throw a error message. I don't know how to fix.
   `C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore\qvariant.h:462: error: 'QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private inline QVariant(void *) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;`

   ```
   QVariant ActionSqlRelationModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
   {
       if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
       {
          return new QPushButton;
       }
       return QVariant();
   }
   ```

I try to use QIdentityProxyModel but it occurs error message.
I just try to override columncount.
[image]

Comment: It seems I should use QAbstructTableModel and QSqlQuery do that by myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I override data(const QModelIndex &index, int role), I have to rewrite all the data, is that avoidable?

Yes. You need to forward to the base class's implementations:

```
void MyModel : public BaseModel {
public:
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    if (index.column() == BaseModel::columnCount()) {
      // extra column
      return "MyData";
    }
    return BaseModel::data(index, role);
  }
  int columnCount() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    return BaseModel::columnCount() + 1;
  }
  ...
};
```

You can also use a `QIdentitityProxyModel` instead of deriving the base model, and override its methods instead - that way you can easily add your additional column no matter what model is used to keep rest of the data.

Specifically:

```
void MyProxy : public QIdentityProxyModel {
public:
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    if (index.column() == BaseModel::columnCount()) {
      // extra column
      return "MyData";
    }
    return QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, role);
  }
  int columnCount() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    return BaseModel::columnCount() + 1;
  }
  MyProxy(QObject * parent = 0) : QIdentityProxyModel(parent) {}
};
```

You'd then use on the view instead of the original model. To let the proxy know what model it's supposed to act as a proxy for, you use the `setSourceModel` method. For example:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTableView view;
  QSqlRelationalTableModel model;
  MyProxy proxy;
  ...
  proxy.setSourceModel(&model);
  view.setModel(&proxy);
  view.show();
  return app.exec();  
}
```

> When I return new QPushButton as QVariant, it throws an error message.

First of all, returning a widget from the `data` method, even if you manage to do it, is not handled by the views. The views will not use such a widget for anything - they will ignore it. So it won't work. I'm showing below how one might do it, but it's to satisfy your curiosity only - it's a utterly useless exercise. Such code "works", but the widget it returns will be ignored.

If your intention is to show a button as a representation for a certain data item, you need to add a custom delegate to the view. The delegate handles the visualization and widgets of items with non-standard requirements. You must reimplement a `QStyledItemDelegate` (or `QAbstractItemDelegate`) and set it on a given column of the view by using `setItemDelegateForColumn`.

To satisfy your curiosity:

`QObject` and classes that derive from it are not copyable, and thus cannot be stored directly in a `QVariant`. Instead, you can store a shared pointer to the object:

```
typedef QSharedPointer<QPushButton> QPushButtonPtr;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QPushButtonPtr)

...

QVariant ActionSqlRelationModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
       return QPushButtonPtr(new QPushButton);
    }
    return QSqlRelationModel::data(index, role); // underlying class's data
}
```

I don't quite know what do you want to achieve by storing buttons in a model. It's of course OK to do so, except that none of the views will know what to do with the button that you provide to them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think your anwser is what I want, but I can't understand something you are talking about.
I will try to understand how QIdentitityProxyModel  works.
And also think about using Qptr.

Comment: @Woody A `QIdentityProxyModel` is a proxy: it forwards requests to the source model, and you can then modify the requests in any way you see fit. By deriving from a `QIdentityProxyModel` you can use any source model you want. By deriving directly from the source model, you're limited to that one model and no other. The storage of a widget using a shared pointer is the only way of storing widgets in a `QVariant`, but I still ask: why do you wish to store widgets in a `QVariant` and in a model? **No existing view can use such widgets!**

Comment: I hope that I can let a row can be pressed or checked.
By pressing the row, it can show a new widget.
That is what I want.
Your explanation for the function of QIdentityProxyModel  is interesting.
I can't understand the meaning of proxy of model.

Comment: @Woody From a dictionary: "a proxy is an agent or substitute authorized to act for another person" Here, a `QIdentityProxyModel` is a model you can use instead of your original model. That model will access the original model for you - you set it by invoking the `setSourceModel` method on the proxy. The proxy can be used on a model of any kind.

Comment: @Woody "By pressing the row, it can show a new widget." No, it cannot, because you can't simply pass the widget to a view through the `data` method of the model. Sure, you can do it, but the views don't know how to handle that, and you'll have a bazillion unneeded widgets that do nothing.